# apt-get is broken and I can't install anything (update issue)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 and found out that I can't install packages anymore. Whatever I try, I get messages such as

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
been moved out of Incoming. 

The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
   anydesk : Depends: libgtkglext1 but it is not installable 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I read somewhere that I should run `apt update` but this is broken. It displays the following:

```
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease 
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security Release   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] 
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease 
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease 
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful Release   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] 
Err:7 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] 
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports Release   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security Release' no longer has a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E: The repository 'archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E: The repository 'archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E: The repository 'archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports Release' does not have a Release file. 
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I already tried `sudo apt-get -f install` and I don't have `synaptic` installed (and can't install it for obvious reasons).

What should I do?

Comment: If you are running 16.04, then why are artful (17.10) sources in your output?  If you were indeed using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, then you system is *likely* polluted by *non-xenial* packages and you've loads to remove to bring your system to a safe state, though a re-install will be far quicker & easier.

Comment: I would suggest running `ubuntu-support-status` to check how many unsupported packages you have on your system. If you installed whilst those artful sources (EOL & unsupported) were there, you'll have lots in the state of 'unsupported' showing the state of your once 16.04 system.

Answer (score 1):

**You are running 17.10, not 16.04. You should migrate to a supported release of Ubuntu.**

Your `apt update` output seems to indicate that you are running 17.10 (Artful).
Here's an example:

```
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
```

See how it says "artful" (17.10) instead of "xenial" (16.04)?

17.10 has reached End of Life, those repositories have been withdrawn (that's why you cannot reach them), and we no longer provide support for it.

There are several easy ways to migrate to a supported release of Ubuntu. We strongly recommend backing up your data before trying any of them, since your system may have problems that we don't know about. A simple `do-release-upgrade` will attempt to migrate your system to 18.04 (bionic), which is fully supported. Alternately, you can create a new install USB for any supported release of Ubuntu, and simply overwrite your current system.